# What is the scope of function within anonymous namespace in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, namespaces

If CPP file defines

```
namespace 
{
 void Function() { ... }
}
```

what is the scope of `Function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File Scope. In this case `Function` is accessible only within the file it is defined in.